# horizontal placement of epslatex gnuplot figure

Tags: gnuplot, pdflatex

I produce a plot with gnuplot with the following code:

```
  set logscale y
  set xlabel "iteration"
  set ylabel "$\\varepsilon$"
  set terminal epslatex color  size 3.5,3.5
  set out 'l2_errors_with_iteration_cc=00001_dt=1200_test.tex'
  plot  "l2_errors_with_iteration_cc=.00001_damping=0.9_dt=0.1200.txt" using 1:2 title 'current' with lines lw 4
  set out
  quit
```

with the following data:

```
 0   2.03616944439
 0   2.03616944439
 2   0.25330118741
 3   0.22665346605
 4   0.20262719150
 5   0.18101252740
 6   0.16160551934
 7   0.14420900466
 8   0.12863525831
 9   0.11470804565
10   0.10226380345
11   0.09115208853
12   0.08123549251
13   0.07238919637
14   0.06450029952
15   0.05746702167
16   0.05119784692
17   0.04561065697
18   0.04063188453
19   0.03619570607
20   0.03224328518
21   0.02872207183
22   0.02558515939
23   0.02279069871
24   0.02030136683
25   0.01808388719
26   0.01610859780
27   0.01434906324
28   0.01278172704
29   0.01138560027
30   0.01014198331
31   0.00903421712
32   0.00804746131
33   0.00716849603
34   0.00638554533
35   0.00568811962
36   0.00506687532
37   0.00451348969
38   0.00402054934
39   0.00358145092
40   0.00319031255
41   0.00284189508
42   0.00253153177
43   0.00225506578
44   0.00200879445
45   0.00178941964
46   0.00159400355
47   0.00141992933
48   0.00126486603
49   0.00112673731
50   0.00100369368
51   0.00089408768
52   0.00079645182
53   0.00070947891
54   0.00063200454
55   0.00056299152
56   0.00050151594
57   0.00044675483
58   0.00039797511
59   0.00035452379
60   0.00031581922
61   0.00028134330
62   0.00025063454
63   0.00022328189
64   0.00019891921
65   0.00017722041
66   0.00015789505
67   0.00014068445
68   0.00012535825
69   0.00011171132
70   0.00009956099
71   0.00008874462
72   0.00007911742
73   0.00007055053
74   0.00006292926
75   0.00005615155
76   0.00005012662
77   0.00004477376
78   0.00004002118
79   0.00003580510
80   0.00003206884
81   0.00002876204
82   0.00002583994
83   0.00002326277
84   0.00002099512
85   0.00001900543
86   0.00001726544
87   0.00001574978
88   0.00001443551
89   0.00001330171
90   0.00001232920
91   0.00001150022
92   0.00001079827
93   0.00001020797
94   0.00000971499
95   0.00000930611
96   0.00000896921
97   0.00000869333
98   0.00000846870
99   0.00000828674
100   0.00000814002
101   0.00000802220
102   0.00000792792
103   0.00000785271
104   0.00000779289
105   0.00000774543
106   0.00000770786
107   0.00000767818
108   0.00000765479
109   0.00000763639
110   0.00000762194
111   0.00000761064
112   0.00000760180
113   0.00000759492
114   0.00000758957
115   0.00000758544
116   0.00000758225
117   0.00000757980
```

It produces a very nice plot with the help of the following tex file:

```
% GNUPLOT: LaTeX picture with Postscript
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package color not loaded in conjunction with
      terminal option `colourtext'%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{Either use 'blacktext' in gnuplot or load the package
      color.sty in LaTeX.}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package graphicx or graphics not loaded%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{The gnuplot epslatex terminal needs graphicx.sty or graphics.sty.}%
    \renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPcolor}{%
    \newif\ifGPcolor
    \GPcolortrue
  }{}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPblacktext}{%
    \newif\ifGPblacktext
    \GPblacktexttrue
  }{}%
  % define a \g@addto@macro without @ in the name:
  \let\gplgaddtomacro\g@addto@macro
  % define empty templates for all commands taking text:
  \gdef\gplbacktext{}%
  \gdef\gplfronttext{}%
  \makeatother
  \ifGPblacktext
    % no textcolor at all
    \def\colorrgb#1{}%
    \def\colorgray#1{}%
  \else
    % gray or color?
    \ifGPcolor
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color[rgb]{#1}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0.3,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}}%
    \else
      % gray
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color{black}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color{black}}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \setlength{\unitlength}{0.0500bp}%
  \begin{picture}(5040.00,5040.00)%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(1342,704){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 1e-06}}%
      \put(1342,1286){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 1e-05}}%
      \put(1342,1867){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 0.0001}}%
      \put(1342,2449){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 0.001}}%
      \put(1342,3030){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 0.01}}%
      \put(1342,3612){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 0.1}}%
      \put(1342,4193){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 1}}%
      \put(1342,4775){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 10}}%
      \put(1474,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 0}}%
      \put(2002,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 20}}%
      \put(2530,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 40}}%
      \put(3059,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 60}}%
      \put(3587,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 80}}%
      \put(4115,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 100}}%
      \put(4643,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 120}}%
      \put(176,2739){\rotatebox{-270}{\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$\varepsilon$}}}%
      \put(3058,154){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}iteration}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(3656,4602){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}current}}%
    }%
    \gplbacktext
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics{l2_errors_with_iteration_cc=00001_dt=1200_test.pdf}}%
    \gplfronttext
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup
```

And produce my document with the following code:

```
\documentclass[aps,showpacs,twocolumn,10pt,pra]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction} \label{sec:Introduction}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\input{l2_errors_with_iteration_cc=00001_dt=1200_test.tex}
\caption{Here we see the error plotted as a function of iteration.}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Now, the question.  In the above code, I can change this line:

```
 \begin{picture}(5040.00,5040.00)%
```

More specifically the first number, making it larger or smaller.  Making it smaller moves the resulting figure to the right.  Making it larger should therefore move the figure to the left.  However, it doesn't.  why?  I would like to do this because I think there is too much space on the left of the plot, the ylabel seems very lonely out there.  I can move it in by changing this line:

```
  \put(176,2739){\rotatebox{-270}{\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$\varepsilon$}}}%
```

increasing (or decreasing) the 176 to whatever value I wish, but that doesn't change the fact that there seems to be much more space than there needs to be.  Interestingly, increasing or decreasing the second 5040.00 -does- actually move the plot up or down as far as one likes (as far as I've tested it), which is why I have the feeling that this may be a bug.

Comment: The same happens for large tics formats, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20522516/2604213. Gnuplot cannot determine the label position and margins correctly for LaTeX formattings.

Comment: Could you share the `set terminal epslatex` line as well?

Comment: not sure what you mean..  I included this line `set terminal epslatex color  size 3.5,3.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reproducing your figure I see that the too much white space on the left is due to the y-label `\varepsilon` in the `gnuplot` file.

I could reproduce a well placed figure by offsetting the y-label with `gnuplot` command

```
set ylabel offset 3,0 "$\\varepsilon$"
```

in your `gnuplot` file. You need not change the positioning in the `begin{picture}` environment.

Comment: This will move the `ylabel` to the right but will not get rid of the white space problem. Setting the margins, e.g. `set lmargin at screen 0.1`, should help with filling the white space on the gnuplot canvas (which measures 3.5 inches of width in this example).

Comment: awesome.  Both the answer of Madhurjya and the suggestion of Miguel lead to acceptable solutions.  However, `set lmargin at screen 0.1` also requires the varepsilon to be re-positioned in the tex file (there may be other ways to do this (it gets set to -290)), so Madhurjya's answer seems to require less work.  thank's!

Comment: @juggler You must combine both answers. Change the ylabel offset and the left margin. And you should avoid changing anything in the TeX-file itself.